# Jquery selection of element with the same index but in another container

Tags: jquery, html

Here is my html:

```
<div id="x">
   <ul>
       <li>a</li>
       <li>b</li>
   </ul>
   <div id="a"></div>
   <div id="b"></div>
</div>
```

Let's say I have the following variable:

```
var div_b = $("#b");
```

The div_b is the second div in div named x. Using the index of div_b variable, I want to select the second li in the ul. How can I do the appropriate selection using jquery? And of course the selection have to work with the first div too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/konan/MDk3Q/

```
$(document).ready(function () {


    $("#x > div").click(function() {
        // set color black 

        $('#x > ul > li').css("color", "black");  


        var idx = $("#x > div").index(this);
        var div_b = $('#x > ul > li').eq(idx);
        div_b.css("color", "red");  

    });



});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:    `$('#x li:eq('+ $('#x div').index( $('#b') )+')')`

Example:

```
var div_b = $("#b");
$('#x li:eq('+ $('#x div').index( div_b )+')').css('color','red')
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/DdauG/)**

Answer (score 0):

assuming you have :

`var div_b = $("#b");`

`$("ul > li").eq($("#x > div").index(div_b));`

**working example :**

http://jsbin.com/iZiPabA/3/edit

so here

```
 <div id="x">
   <ul>
       <li>a</li>
       <li>bc</li>
       <li>ad</li>
       <li>be</li>
       <li>b2</li>
   </ul>
     <div id="a"></div>
     <div id="a1"></div>
     <div id="a2"></div>
     <div id="b"></div>
     <div id="a3"></div>

</div>
```

it is :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>[**Fiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/dzyKb/1)</kbd>

```
$('#b,#a').click(function () {
    var index = $(this).index('div');
    alert($('#x ul li:nth-child(' + index + ')').text());
});
```

or

<kbd>[**Fiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/dzyKb/2)</kbd>

```
$('#x div').click(function () {
    var index = $(this).index('div');
    alert($('#x ul li:nth-child(' + index + ')').text());
});
```

References

[:nth-child()](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)

Comment: first of all i am not `the downvoter` .. your code is perfect but it should not be bind on one dibv only